# Hosting a web application that uploads and downloads files without graphical interface

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, hosting

I am a .NET developer, I created an ASP .NET web application which communicates with windows app clients and xamarin android clients. The web application in fact is a bunch of web services which upload data (images) to the disk of a web server, and manage SQL Server databases. The objective of the entire system is to create budgets for the building company of my brother's, he is a contractor.

I want to host the web application on a shared server, but my web application lacks a web page or user interface, and according to most of the hosting companies in the terms of use they say that files on their servers must be related to the website which one should host.

Are there hosting companies willing to host an application like mine?

Comment: From your requirement above, you need to purchase dedicated or VPS hosting. You can consider asphostportal, their dedicated server is very cheap and comes with SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for web application hosting, not website hosting. Azure App Services will do what you're looking for but that might be overkill. This also might be better answered in one of the other stack sites.